# Grails: specify number of digits for integer in domain class

Tags: validation, grails, integer, grails-orm, digits

Is there some better way than validators to enforce an integer be exactly, for example, 2 digits?

In my fantasy world I would do something like this:

```
class FantasyDomainClass{
  Integer[2] twoDigitInteger  //fantasy world knows I mean base 10
}
```

Maybe BigInteger?

Based on the answers posed, I am considering I may not want an integer as '01' is an acceptable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [a custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Constraints/validator.html) and set it as

```
class FantasyDomainClass {

Integer twoDigitInteger

static constraints = { 
  twoDigitInteger validator: { 
    return (it.toString().size() <= 2) 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set a contraint on the field that it be between 10 and 99:

```
class FantasyDomainClass {
    Integer twoDigitInteger

    static constraints = {
        twoDigitInteger min:10, max:99
    }
}
```